# Execute normal is inserting "<tab>" instead of hitting tab key

Tags: vimscript, snippets

I am trying to make a function that creates a new line and hits the tab key (aka 2 spaces / 4 spaces; what ever is set).  I can do it easily with a keybinding:

```
:inoremap <leader>ind <esc>o<tab>
```

But when I try to execute this from a function:

```
function! Indent_New_Line()
  execute "normal! o<tab>"
endfunction

:inoremap <leader>ind <esc>:call Indent_New_Line()<cr>
```

the `<tab>` gets printed literally instead of a tab char:

```
|def foo
|<tab>
|end
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?  I couldn't find very much about this..

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to insert a `\` before the `<tab>`

Now the code will look like this instead:

```
execute "normal! o\<tab>"
```

Comment: Awesome thank you.  What is weird is that I tried this already and the first time it didn't work, but now it does.. I'm not sure what I changed since then but at least it's working now.  Thank you!

Comment: @MitchellWoodbine This won't work if you are not inside a string. For example `:normal o\<tab>` will not work since it is not inside a string. `\<tab>` works inside a string because the `\` escapes the `<tab>` (or at least according to my understanding)